# Convergence of a sequence with both sin and cos

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence, absolute-convergence

I'm trying to figure out whether the following series converges absolutely or conditionally or whether it diverges. I am stuck on the following one that involved both sin and cosine: 
$$
\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{\sin(n)}{n^2+\cos(n)}
$$ 
Any guidance would be greatly appreciated however :)

Comment: Perhaps you can check whether it converges absolutely or not.

Comment: Also, as a friendly psa, you can check out the link [here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) to learn how to properly type mathematics on this site to make your equations readable.

Comment: That's what I'm asked to do but I'm confused as how to start :)

Comment: Hint: Try and use the fact that $-1\leq\sin(n)\leq 1$. Similar for $\cos(n)$.

Comment: I considered that, is it okay to use the squeeze theorem would I separate the sin and cosine part of the series??

Comment: Well I think you'll get more out of this problem of you wrote what you tried and attempted. Otherwise, you're just fishing for answers. Another hint, use the comparison test on the absolute value of the terms.

Comment: You can use Limit Comparison with $\sum_1^\infty \frac{1}{n^2}$. Or else use Comparison with $\sum_2^\infty  \frac{1}{n^2/2}$.

Answer (score 2):

**HINT:**

$$\left|\frac{\sin n}{n^2+\cos n}\right|\le \frac{1}{n^2-1}$$

for $n>1$.

Comment: Technically you also have to verify $\cos 1 \neq -1$ even if you accept $\cos n \geq -1$, otherwise the series might blow up with the first term and not be defined.

Comment: @user2566092 this didn't claim to be a full solution, and checking that $\cos 1\neq -1$ is a trivial matter.

Comment: I have used the following: 
the sum from {n=1} to infty  of (sin(n))/(n^2 + cos(n)) < (1)/(n^2 -1) < (1)/{n^2} where by the p series the test converges so the series therefore converges absolutely??

Comment: $\frac{1}{n^2-1} < \frac{1}{n^2}$ is not necessarily true. But you can invoke the limit comparison test between the two series $\sum \frac{1}{n^2-1}$ and $\sum \frac{1}{n^2}$. The p-series test and limit comparison test tells us that $\sum \frac{1}{n^2-1}$  must converge.

Comment: So as long as I state that by the comparison test these series hold, the p-series test tells us this so the original series must converge?

Comment: Yup. That's pretty much it.

Comment: and it converges absolutely ?? Thankyou!!

Comment: @mathnewbie I didn't make such a claim. However, $1/(n^2-1)<2/n^2$.

Comment: Yes, since the series converges absolutely, it'll also have to converge as well. No problem.

Comment: @Dr.MV, I was speaking with Chloe. She wrote that in her comment.

Comment: @user2566092 I gave a HINT.

Comment: @Dr.MV I was simply adding to your hint, in case OP took limit comparison alone according to your hint and forgot to check the first term. A hint added to a hint. I also gave you +1, indicating I think you gave a good answer.

Comment: @user2566082 No worry.  And your points are great added hints.  Much appreciative and thanks for the up vote!